# Export comma delimited data to new table in MariaDB 10.3

Tags: mariadb

How can I export all the data from Genre separated by commas into a new table ?
Below is my product table.

[image]

And this is the types table, basically I want to insert each (separated by comma) results from the Genre table and insert them into new rows in the types table.

[image]

Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.3.36-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: And do not forget to specify MYSQL version (the output for `SELECT VERSION();`).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to write a stored procedure (or function). The STRRCHR() builtin will tell you the index of the last occurrence of a character alternatively the SUBSTRING_INDEX() will return the Nth sub-string in a set with a character separator. Looks like your solution will also need TRIM()

However it's also possible from non-procedural SQL using a row-multiplier table/cartesian join

Applying the non-procedural method.....

```
INSERT INTO normalized (genre_id, string_value)
SELECT g.id, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.genre, ',', rm.id))
FROM genre g
JOIN row_multiplier rm
WHERE rm.id<CHAR_LENGTH(g.genre)/2 /* small optimization */
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.genre, ',', rm.id) IS NOT NULL;
```